# Question about quotient groups of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$, if for some $n$, $H/nH = 0$ and $([G : H], n) = 1$, then is it true that $G/nG = 0$?

Comment: I may not be understanding the notation fully... but wouldn't a nondivisible group $G$ with a divisible subgroup $H$ be a counterexample? Maybe the index condition rules this out, somehow. I don't have a specific example in mind, just the strategy.

Comment: This is about Abelian Groups. So any subgroup is a divider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will write the group multiplicatively. Choose integers $u,v \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $u \cdot n + v \cdot [G:H]=1$. For every $g \in G$ we have $g^{[G:H]} \in H$ by Lagrange, so it's an $n$th power. It follows that also $g=(g^u)^n \cdot (g^{[G:H]})^v$ is an $n$th power.